# Hibernate stored procedure call hangs when called multiple times

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

Basically we have a bunch of databases, and then a "master" database, which collects and calculates some statistics.

I then have a stored procedure which I can call, to get statistics from a given date-range (Which I then save in my database).

The problem is, when I run my unittests, all works fine. A single call to the stored procedure returns the expected data. Though when I try to call it multiple time, fx with this little hack:

```
@Test
public void multipleRequests()  {

    StatisticManager statisticManager = new StatisticManager();
    List<Errorstatistic> allStats = new ArrayList<>();
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

    for(int i = 1; i <= 31; i++){
        String string = "01/" + i + "/2017";

        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = format.parse(string);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't parse date.");
        }
        allStats.addAll(statisticManager.getNewStatistics(date));
    }
    statisticManager.persistNewStatistics(allStats);
}
```

Then only the first request ( 01/01-2017 ) comes through. I can then change then loop to go from 2 and restart it, and 2 will go through but hangs with 3. A quick sys-out debugging shows, that it hangs when trying to call the stored procedure the second time:

```
Get statistics called
Begin called
Returning em
feb. 06, 2017 7:52:34 PM org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl     prepareForNamedParameters
WARN: HHH000456: Named parameters are used for a callable statement, but     database metadata indicates named parameters are not supported.
Getting list
Hibernate: 
{call sp_errorratestat(?,?)}
Got list
Closing
Closed
Received data.
Get statistics called
Begin called
Returning em
Getting list
Hibernate: 
{call sp_errorratestat(?,?)}
```

I just can't seem to find out what's happening. I've tried removing locks, inserting up to 8 seconds of sleep-time, creating everything new in the loop - but nothing works.

Can anybody help me out here?

**StatisticManager**

```
public class StatisticManager {
    ErrorStatisticProcedureDAO obiDao = new ErrorStatisticProcedureDAO();
    ErrorStatisticDAO localDao = new ErrorStatisticDAO();

    public void persistNewStatistics(List<Errorstatistic> errorstatistics) {
        localDao.saveList(errorstatistics);
    }

    public List<Errorstatistic>  getNewStatistics(Date from) {
        List<Errorstatistic> originalStatistics = obiDao.getNewStatistics(setFrom(from), setTo(from));
        System.out.println("Received data.");
        return originalStatistics;
    }


    public List<Errorstatistic> getNewStatistics(Date from, Date to) {
        List<Errorstatistic> originalStatistics = obiDao.getNewStatistics(setFrom(from), setTo(to));
        System.out.println("Received data.");
        return originalStatistics;
    }



    private Date setFrom(Date date){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 01);
        return cal.getTime();
    }

    private Date setTo(Date date){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
        return cal.getTime();
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
    public class ErrorStatisticProcedureDAO {
    protected EntityManager em = ObiPersistenceManager.INSTANCE.getEntityManager();
    private Object lock = new Object();

    protected EntityManager begin() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println("Begin called");
            if (!em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                em.getTransaction().begin();
            }
            System.out.println("Returning em");
        }
        return em;
    }

    protected void close() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println("Closing");
            if (em.isOpen()) {
                if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                    em.getTransaction().commit();
                    em.clear();
                }
                System.out.println("Closed");
            }
        }
    }


    public List<Errorstatistic> getNewStatistics(Date from, Date to){
        System.out.println("Get statistics called");
        begin();
        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("sp_errorratestat");
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("fromTs", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("toTs", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN);

        storedProcedure.setParameter("fromTs", (long) from.getTime() / 1000);
        storedProcedure.setParameter("toTs", (long)to.getTime() / 1000);

        System.out.println("Getting list");
        List data = storedProcedure.getResultList();
        System.out.println("Got list");
        List<Errorstatistic> errorstatistics = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator itr = data.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();


            Errorstatistic errorstatistic = new Errorstatistic();
            errorstatistic.setDevicestate(obj[0] != null ? ((String) obj[0]) : null);
            errorstatistic.setIftype(obj[1] != null ? (String) obj[1] : null);
            errorstatistic.setServices(obj[2] != null ? (String) obj[2] : null);
            errorstatistic.setHardware(obj[3] != null ? (String) obj[3] : null);
            errorstatistic.setFirmware(obj[4] != null ?  (String) obj[4] : null);
            errorstatistic.setTicketstotal(obj[5] != null ? ((BigDecimal) obj[5]).intValueExact() : null);
            errorstatistic.setBootstotal(obj[6] != null ? ((BigDecimal) obj[6]).intValueExact() : null);
            errorstatistic.setCriticaldevices(obj[7] != null ? ((BigDecimal) obj[7]).intValueExact() : null);
            errorstatistic.setUnstabledevices(obj[8] != null ? ((BigDecimal) obj[8]).intValueExact() : null);
            errorstatistic.setDate(obj[9] != null ? (Date) obj[9] : null);
            errorstatistic.setDevicetime(obj[11] != null ? ((BigDecimal) obj[11]).doubleValue() : null);
            errorstatistic.setBootcausecountAdslFailure(obj[12] != null ? ((BigDecimal) obj[12]).intValueExact() : null);
            errorstatistic.setBootcausecountPllLosinglock(obj[13] != null ? ((BigDecimal) obj[13]).intValueExact() : null);
            errorstatistic.setBootcausecountPoweronHwreset(obj[14] != null ? ((BigDecimal) obj[14]).intValueExact() : null);
            errorstatistic.setBootcausecountServerdown(obj[15] != null ? ((BigDecimal) obj[15]).intValueExact() : null);
            errorstatistic.setBootcausecountSoftreset(obj[16] != null ? ((BigDecimal) obj[16]).intValueExact() : null);
            errorstatistic.setBootcausecountUnknownreset(obj[17] != null ? ((BigDecimal) obj[17]).intValueExact() : null);
            errorstatistic.setBootcausecountWatchdogreset(obj[18] != null ? ((BigDecimal) obj[18]).intValueExact() : null);
            errorstatistic.setDevicecount(obj[19] != null ? ((BigInteger) obj[19]).longValue() : null);

            errorstatistics.add(errorstatistic);
        }
        close();
        return errorstatistics;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the stored procedure do? Maybe you could share the code or the gist of it.

Comment: Hi Mick. I don't have the stopro code. But essentially it's a view of multiple tables in the master db :).
Though I know it works fine, if I call it multiple times through fx MySQL workbench.

Comment: I had a similar behavior when I was working on the same tables from SQL Developer while executing the procedure from the Java Application. It seemed that somehow, even though I committed and closed the SQL Developer, the Java application had issues with restoring the normal behavior. I had to reset the JDBC connection before everything came back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from this snippet:

```
protected EntityManager begin() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        System.out.println("Begin called");
        if (!em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
        }
        System.out.println("Returning em");
    }
    return em;
}
```

and continuing with this one:

```
protected EntityManager em = ObiPersistenceManager.INSTANCE.getEntityManager();
```

I can only conclude that you are using a singleton `EntityManager` which you then need to synchronize among multiple threads. Otherwise, why would you need the synchronize block?

Well, [as stated in the Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html), the Persistence Context is not thread-safe:

> It is not intended that implementors be threadsafe. Instead, each
>   thread/transaction should obtain its own instance from a
>   SessionFactory.

Both Java EE and Spring allow you to inject an `EntityManager` through the `@PersistenceContext` annotation. This is a very good practice since the lifecycle of the `EntityManager` is bound to the current transaction boundary. So, each service layer application-level transaction gets a single transactional context which, in turn, uses it's own `EntityManager` local variable.

I suspect that you can replicate the issue in your unit test if you execute it concurrently. Just use a `CountDownLatch` to orchestrate multiple threads that try to call the same service methods.

Comment: Hi Vlad.

Thank you so much. I will absolutely tix the threading issues. I've used this kind of entitymanager setup in multiple programs, so I guess I have some work in front of me. 

I was actually - a couple of hours ago - able to replicate the error in MySQL workbench, by executing a number of statements after eachother. I've made a ticket with the people of the database, to find the error.

Though I belive your input is very valuable, and I will definitely change my setup.

Thank you. :)